# How to segment in SQL using approx_quantiles

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the ga_sessions sample data in BigQuery and I was aiming to divide the customers into segments based on how often they placed an order using APPROX_QUANTILES. Ideally I want the output to tell me which segment the customer belongs to based on their orders.

Unfortunately I cannot get the code to run properly as I now get a 1 for each segment and the 100% segment returns 36 everytime. Any idea on how to improve this query?

```
WITH transdata AS (
SELECT
  DISTINCT fullVisitorId AS VisitorId
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT FORMAT('%s%i',fullVisitorId,visitId)) AS uniqueVisits
  ,SUM(totals.transactions) AS total_transactions
  ,SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) AS total_transaction_revenue
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20170801'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
)

-- determine percentiles for total transactions per customer
SELECT
  a.*
  ,b.percentiles[offset (20)] AS v20
  ,b.percentiles[offset (40)] AS v40
  ,b.percentiles[offset (60)] AS v60
  ,b.percentiles[offset (80)] AS v80
  ,b.percentiles[offset (100)] AS v100
FROM
  transdata AS a,
  (SELECT APPROX_QUANTILES(total_transactions, 100) percentiles FROM transdata) AS b
```

Comment: It's not the query problem but data problem, **total_transactions** shows highly right-skewed distribution.  You'd better consider another segmentation scheme rather than percentiles.

Comment: wow I cant believe I missed that haha, thanks for pointing that out!